# Watch ng-model whilst using minlength?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, validation

I'm trying to watch the value of `ng-model` whilst also using the `minlength` validation. The problem is the model value remains empty/undefined until the validation criteria is met.

#### HTML

```
<input ng-model="xyz" minlength="8" />
```

#### JS

```
$scope.$watch('xyz', function(val) {
  // Will either be undefined or a
  // string bigger than or equal
  // to 8 characters.
  console.log(val);
});
```

I know I could just `substring` the element's value, but this code is implemented in a directive which uses `$compile`, so ideally I'd prefer to watch the model value.

Any thoughts on how to resolve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngModelOptions

allowInvalid: boolean value which indicates that the model can be set with values that did not validate correctly instead of the default behavior of setting the model to undefined.